# Convert HH:mm:ss,dd-MM-yyyy from string to date format

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a string of the below format HH:mm:ss,dd-MM-yyyy into DateTime value
 and i am not able to can you please help

```
GetDateTime = "16:30:52,11-14-2013"
  DateTime currentDatetime;
  DateTime.TryParseExact(GetDateTime, "HH:mm:ss,dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out currentDatetime);
```

and i am getting

1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

can any one help !

Comment: `11-14-2013` -> `dd-MM-yyyy` aren't you inverting month and days ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Month is in wrong format. hence "Parse" fails.

Is there any month called `14`? I think you mean `MM-dd-yyyy`?

Answer (score 2):

Either change to

```
GetDateTime = "16:30:52,14-11-2013";
```

**OR**

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(GetDateTime, "HH:mm:ss,MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out currentDatetime);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string dateString = "14/11/2013 16:30:52"; // <-- Valid
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```